# Spark Structured streaming replacing values of a column

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following dataframe

```
val tDataJsonDF = kafkaStreamingDFParquet
   .filter($"value".contains("tUse"))
   .filter($"value".isNotNull)
   .selectExpr("cast (value as string) as tdatajson", "cast (topic as string) as env")
   .select(from_json($"tdatajson", schema = ParquetSchema.tSchema).as("data"), $"env".as("env"))
   .select("data.*", "env")
   .select($"date", <--YYYY/MM/dd
           $"time",
           $"event",
           $"serviceGroupId",
           $"userId",
           $"env")
```

This streaming dataframe has a column date which has the format - `YYYY/MM/dd`.

Due to this when I use this column as a partitioning column in my parquet write Spark creates the partition as `date=2018%04%12`.

Is there way I can modify the column value on the fly in the above code so that the date value is `YYYY-MM-dd` or `YYYYMMd`.

Parquet write query:

```
val tunerQuery = tunerDataJsonDF
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path",pathtodata )
  .option("checkpointLocation", pathtochkpt)
  .partitionBy("date","env","serviceGroupId")
  .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Spark 2.2+

```
tDataJsonDF.withColumn("formatted_date",date_format(to_date(col("date"), "YYYY/MM/dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```